# Como fazer comparação com o Guid Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, Gostaria de fazer essa comparação usando um `Guid`, `public Guid ClienteID {get;set;}`. Esse código funciona usando um `int`, eu faço um `if`, se o meu `ClienteID == 0` eu salvo, e se não for igual a 0 eu altero.

quero um jeito de poder fazer mais o menos isso para pode salvar e alterar.

```
    public void Salvar(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (cliente.ClienteID == 0)
        {                
            cliente.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
            _contexto.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        }
        else
        {                
            Cliente cli = _contexto.Clientes.Find(cliente.ClienteID);

            if (cli != null)
            {
                cli.Nome = cliente.Nome;
                cli.Cpf = cliente.Cpf;
                cli.Telefone = cliente.Telefone;
                cli.Email = cliente.Email;
                cli.Cep = cliente.Cep;
                cli.Endereco = cliente.Endereco;
                cli.Bairro = cliente.Bairro;
                cli.Numero = cliente.Numero;
                cli.Complemento = cliente.Complemento;
                cli.DataCadastro = cli.DataCadastro;
            }
        }
        _contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Esse `Salvar` é chamado exatamente onde?

Comment: Só faltou você colocar a `classe` Cliente, na sua pergunta, mas, eu fiz as duas formas na resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você só precisa comparar a propriedade com Guid.Empty

Ex.:

```
cliente.ClienteGuid == Guid.Empty;
```

Sobre o código apresentado: Esse segundo if, não é necessário, dessa maneira até vai funcionar, mas vai te trazer alguns problemas depois. Por exemplo, todas as vezes que você criar uma propriedade nova vai ter que entrar no método de salvamento e editá-lo.

Você pode simplificar tudo para:

```
public void Salvar(Cliente cliente)
{
    if(cliente.ClienteGuid == Guid.Empty)
    {
        cliente.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
        _contexto.Clientes.Add(cliente);
    }
    else
    {
        _contexto.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Pode ser que tenha alguns erros de digitação porque escrevi pelo celular, qualquer coisa me avisa pelos comentários que eu edito logo que puder.

Answer (score 1):

*Teste se a variável do tipo* [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) **é** `empty`:

***Exemplo:***

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Guid Id = Guid.Empty;

            if (Id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guid is empty");                
            }

            Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            if (!(Id == Guid.Empty))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guid not empty");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

[***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/fork/2GfPUL)

---

Outra forma que pode acontecer é quanto definimos o tipo [System.Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Guid? Id = null;

    if (Id.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guid is not null");                
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guid is null");                
    }

    Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    if (Id.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guid not null");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

[***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/fork/yTtolL)

Em sua pergunta o trecho de código pode variar de acordo com essas maneiras:

***Guid.Empty***

---

```
public void Salvar(Cliente cliente)
{
    if (cliente.ClienteID == Guid.Empty)
    {                
        cliente.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
        _contexto.Clientes.Add(cliente);
    }
    else
    {                
        Cliente cli = _contexto.Clientes.Find(cliente.ClienteID);

        if (cli != null)
        {
            cli.Nome = cliente.Nome;
            cli.Cpf = cliente.Cpf;
            cli.Telefone = cliente.Telefone;
            cli.Email = cliente.Email;
            cli.Cep = cliente.Cep;
            cli.Endereco = cliente.Endereco;
            cli.Bairro = cliente.Bairro;
            cli.Numero = cliente.Numero;
            cli.Complemento = cliente.Complemento;
            cli.DataCadastro = cli.DataCadastro;
        }
    }
    _contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

***Guid == null***

---

```
public void Salvar(Cliente cliente)
{
    if (!cliente.ClienteID.HasValue)
    {                
        cliente.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
        _contexto.Clientes.Add(cliente);
    }
    else
    {                
        Cliente cli = _contexto.Clientes.Find(cliente.ClienteID);

        if (cli != null)
        {
            cli.Nome = cliente.Nome;
            cli.Cpf = cliente.Cpf;
            cli.Telefone = cliente.Telefone;
            cli.Email = cliente.Email;
            cli.Cep = cliente.Cep;
            cli.Endereco = cliente.Endereco;
            cli.Bairro = cliente.Bairro;
            cli.Numero = cliente.Numero;
            cli.Complemento = cliente.Complemento;
            cli.DataCadastro = cli.DataCadastro;
        }
    }
    _contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Referencias:**

- [`Estrutura Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Campo Guid.Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.guid.empty(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Estrutura Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você colocar a resposta no contexto dele. Sua resposta está correta, mas possivelmente a dúvida faz parte de uma regra de negócio do ASP.NET MVC.